# Root test proof explanation?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Why is it that $\lim\, sup\:  a_{n}\: \leq C \lt 1 $ imply $\left |a_{n}  \right |\leq \, \frac{C+1}{2} < 1$ for almost all $n\, \in \mathbb{N}$

I got it from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test#Proof

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is wrong. Let $a_n:=C$ for even $n$ and $a_n=-2$ for odd $n$. Then $\lim\sup_n a_n=C$, but $|a_n|=2>1$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: I mention this in my answer. The statement on Wikipedia needs some absolute values added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\limsup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n\le C$ means that for any $\varepsilon\gt0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $a_n\le C+\varepsilon$ for all $n\ge N$.

Since $C\lt1$, we can take $\varepsilon=\frac{1-C}3$. For $n\ge N$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
a_n
&\le C+\frac{1-C}3\\
&=\frac{1+2C}3\\
&=\frac{C+1}2-\frac{1-C}6\\
&\lt\frac{C+1}2
\end{align}
$$
If $a_n\ge0$, then this is fine. Otherwise, $a_n$ might be very negative and still satisfy $\limsup\limits_na_n\le C$, so there is no way to bound $\left|a_n\right|$ given what is given above.

---

The statement on Wikipedia *should* read
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|a_n\right|\le C\lt1\implies\left|a_n\right|\le\frac{1+C}2\lt1
$$
for all but finitely many $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The wikipedia proof is rather clunky. This is true for $\limsup |a_n|\leq C$ when $0<C<1$ since this implies $C<(C+1)/2$.

For almost all, by definition of limsup, there exists an $N$ such that $|a_n|\leq C+(1/2-C/2)$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: Thanks! But some things still bother me. don't see why it says ''almost all n'' and how $\\lim\, sup\:  a_{n}\: \leq C$ becomes $\\left |a_{n} \right |\leq C $

Comment: @John11: see edit